# Angular; building for production gives unclear error

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I have build an app in Angular. In normal mode (debug) it works fine. But when I want to build it for production I get an error:

*An unhandled exception occurred: Maximum call stack size exceeded
See "C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-fYDsLg\angular-errors.log" for further details.*

When I open that file I see this:

> [error] RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>
> at Object.isInJSFile (C:\Users{username}\source\repos{appname}\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:10139:24)
>
> at checkBinaryExpression (C:\Users{username{\source\repos{appname}\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:53226:20)
>
> at checkExpressionWorker (C:\Users{username{\source\repos{appname}\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:53986:28)
>       at checkExpression (C:\Users{username{\source\repos{appname}\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:53878:38)
>
> at checkBinaryLikeExpression (C:\Users{username{\source\repos{appname}\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:53241:28)
>
> at checkBinaryExpression (C:\Users{username{\source\repos{appname}\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:53229:20)
>       at checkExpressionWorker (C:\Users{username{\source\repos{appname}\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:53986:28)
>
> at checkExpression (C:\Users{username{\source\repos{appname}\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:53878:38)
>
> at checkBinaryLikeExpression (C:\Users{username{\source\repos{appname}\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:53241:28)
>
> at checkBinaryExpression (C:\Users{username{\source\repos{appname}\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:53229:20)
>
> at checkExpressionWorker (C:\Users{username{\source\repos{appname}\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:53986:28)
>
> at checkExpression (C:\Users{username{\source\repos{appname}\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:53878:38)
>
> at checkBinaryLikeExpression (C:\Users{username{\source\repos{appname}\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:53241:28)
>
> at checkBinaryExpression (C:\Users{username{\source\repos{appname}\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:53229:20)
>
> at checkExpressionWorker (C:\Users{username{\source\repos{appname}\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:53986:28)
>
> at checkExpression (C:\Users{username{\source\repos{appname}\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:53878:38)

(I remove my username and appname because of personal and other information, but you get the point)

I have no idea where to start searching for this error. Rebuilding the app is not an option since it is almost finished (after a few months).

Comment: Try `ng serve --prod`, sometimes you get more comprehensive error messages this way.

Comment: do you lazy load modules?

Comment: @mbojko When I do that, no error is shown and it compiles correctly

Comment: @trees_are_great I am not an Angular expert.. so... How can I see that and is it bad?

Comment: When you have your routing file. Do you just have a route and a url, or do you also have loadChildren: in there ?

Comment: Nope, I don't use routing since it all happens on one page, I see a app-routing.module.ts, but the routes are empty. The routing file (and module) is in the "imports" of app.module.ts

Comment: @JohanFrijhof This link help you to figure out the error https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9383

Comment: @Abhishek Thanks. I tried some suggestions in there, but I don't use anything from Google (yet).

Comment: @JohanFrijhof Try to remove `node_modules, package-lock.json` do cache clean, run npm install and rebuild your application

Comment: @Abhishek Sadly, that didn't work. Still same issue, but the errors log shows other files